# Tower of dice - Abstracting a practical problem to a mathematical method

Tags: puzzle, dice

This question arose when playing yahtzee with some friends. Not entirely sure if I'm in the right area, but hope you can help.

*How many dice do you need to create a tower whose walls have the same number of eyes?*

Through brute force we found that you could do it with 2 dice and 4 dice, so then any multiple or sum of these would be a solution.

But how can you solve such a problem generally?

Or to rephrase it into a hypothesis:

*There are no dice towers where every wall has an equal number of eyes and an odd number of dice.*

Comment: I have no idea how to tag this, but I am sure that [logic] is not right.

Comment: @Asaf: [tag:dice] seemed like a natural choice :-)

Comment: @joriki: Now there's choice involved? :-)

Comment: @Asaf: Wherever you are, there's choice :-)

Comment: @joriki: I see I have no choice about that... :-)

Answer (score 3):

Your hypothesis is correct. A die has a total of $21$ eyes, $7$ on each pair of opposite sides, so it always has $14$ on the walls no matter how you place it. Since $14=3\cdot4+2$, the number of eyes on the walls is not an integer multiple of $4$ if you have an odd number of dice, so you can't have the same number of eyes on all $4$ walls in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Each two opposite sides of a die has totally 7 eyes in common (1+6, 2+5, 3+4). If quantity of dice is odd, then sum of numbers of eyes on two opposite walls would be odd.